# Data Type Mismatch Vb.net Access

Tags: database, vb.net

[image]I am trying to insert data into my Access database using vb for an application I am building.  I have been BEATING my had off of an invisible wall trying to get the data to enter into the database. Below is the code, below that I will explain it more.

```
 Private Sub btnSubmitExpense_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitExpense.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\PFADatabase.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into Expenses ([ExpenseTypeID], [DateOfExpense],[AmountOfExpense]) Values(?,?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ExpenseTypeID", CType(cboCategoryOfExpense.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DateOfExpense", CType(dateOfExpense.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AmountOfExpense", CType(txtAmountOfExpense.Text, String)))

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        'clear the form below
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

[ExpenseTypeID] is actually a lookup.  The object is a combobox in vb that I have programmed above the code I posted here. 
[DateOfExpense] is also a Date object in VB.  I just dragged it over.  I want that to be associated with everything in that table. 
[AmountOfExpense] is again, tied into the db.

Basically a user enters the date using the tool, then chooses a category of their expense and then enters the amount.  This is all one table but the expenseType is a Lookup actually within Access to another table so we could have the dropdown.  Everything works well until I click the save button.  Then whenever i do that I get the exception the type is mismatched.  How do I fix that?  I'm GUESSING it is the text string being wrong, but I've tried other things so I am thinking it is a bit more than that which is why I came here to you professionals to get input.

Thank you.

EDIT: The error is coming in at

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression. "

```
'START THE POPULATE THE COMBO BOXES

    'Gets the database and makes the connection

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="

    dataFile = "C:\PFADatabase.accdb"

    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString


    'Generates a query command
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ExpenseType] FROM [ExpenseType]", myConnection)
    myConnection.Open() 'Opens connection
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader


    While dr.Read
        cboCategoryOfExpense.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
    End While
    myConnection.Close()


    'END THE POPULATE OF COMBO BOXES
```

As you can see in the comments, it is saying how the combo boxes are populated.

EDIT: In the picture under Expenses is the main table.  The circled value is the FK and it's leading to the PK of the ExpenseType.  The data we are pulling the drop down from is the ExpenseType under ExpenseType. From what I understand, you guys are saying, and I agree, it's writing to the PK of ExpenseType and not the data. ALL I want it to do is keep the data categorized for a graph we will be using.

Comment: The error message talks about a mismatch between the datatypes of the values in your parameters and the datatype of the columns on your database table. You are passing strings in the parameters collection, are your database fields of text type? (or are they numeric and dates?)

Comment: @Steve one is a date, the other is a text lookup, the final one is a currency.

Comment: And you pass strings. Clearly the database doesn't like. You should convert the values to the appropriate datatype before adding the converted value to your parameters. And do not use the Parameter constructor without specifying the type

Comment: @Steve so would I on my form put the object.toString()?

Comment: Then change `CType()` 'String' argument or wrap them in respective [conversion types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kca3w8x6.aspx). And are you sure ExpenseTypeID is a string type?

Comment: @Steve actually, it's not.  I just went and looked at how she made the DB.  she put a one to many to the autonumber (which I am unsure how that is going to work now -_-). I'm going to check out the link you supplied.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Parfait, it's not a string, as I just said.  I just looked it an autonumber.  I think I am going to have to figure out how to change that some how.  She set it up as a autonumber for the lookup.  Any ideas?

Comment: `I have been BEATING my had off `.  Dont do that.  You'll go blind.

Comment: @Plutonix, hey I am over here xD.  lol, that legit cracked me up.  I'm so agitated...that definitely was needed lol.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input to the appropriate datatype as required by your columns. If you don't specify the datatype of your parameters and pass always strings then you are easy target of this kind of errors

```
   ...
   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

   Dim expID As Integer
   if Not Int32.TryParse(cboCategoryOfExpense.Text, expID) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid integer")
        return 
   End If
   cmd.Parameters.Add("ExpenseTypeID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = expID

   Dim dtExp as DateTime
   if Not DateTime.TryParse(dateOfExpense.Text, dtExp) Then 
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date")
        return 
   End If
   cmd.Parameters.Add("DateOfExpense", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtExp

   Dim amount As Decimal
   if Not Decimal.TryParse(txtAmountOfExpense.Text, amount) Then 
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Decimal")
        return 
   End If
   cmd.Parameters.Add("AmountOfExpense", OleDbType.Currency).Value = amount
   ....
```

**Looking at your edit and comments, perhaps this is what you need**

```
' Be sure to have a combobox with DropDownList style to avoid
' user entering an unexpected value then....

'Load the combobox from the table ExpenseType 
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ExpenseTypeID], " & _
                           "[ExpenseType] FROM [ExpenseType]", myConnection)
myConnection.Open() 'Opens connection
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
Dim dt = new DataTable()
dt.Load(dr)

cboCategoryOfExpense.DataSource = dt

' The visible part of the combo contains value from ExpenseType field
cboCategoryOfExpense.DisplayMember = "ExpenseType"

' The hidden part refers to the ExpenseTypeID field
cboCategoryOfExpense.ValueMember = "ExpenseTypeID"
...
```

and now when converting the combobox value you coud write

```
   Dim expID As Integer

   ' Sanity check in case the user want to insert but has not 
   ' selected anything from the combobox 
   if cboCategoryOfExpense.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Select an Expense")
        return 
   End if
   cmd.Parameters.Add("ExpenseTypeID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cboCategoryOfExpense.SelectedValue)
   ....
```

Comment: Thank you :).  I tried that, and I got the invalid integer error.  I'm guessing it's because, now that I went and looked at her DB, she has the lookup as an autonumber.  I don't think you can convert those can you or handle them since they are in a table of their own?

Comment: Autonumbers columns are of integer datatype. If you get the _Invalid integer_ message then it is your combobox text that is not a number. How do you load that combo? You should use the _ValueMember_ and _DisplayMember_ properties to have a text displayed and an integer value to pass to your query reading the SelectedValue property

Comment: I edited the original post for populating the combo box.  It's coming from another table. I used some tutorial on doing.  Is there a tutorial for doing that, too?

Comment: ExpenseType is the text string, you need the ExpenseTypeID from the same table. Do you have it in your ExpenseType table?

Comment: Edited the answer, but now I am taking a break for the night, hope to have helped.

Comment: You can't insert anything into an autonumber column. Autonumbers are auto generated and read only.

Comment: @Steve I had added those (sorry it took so long, my grams called), I am still getting the invalid integer. Thank you for your help though!  Maybe if you get frisky, you'll want to finish tomorrow lol.  If not, then thank you anyway!

Comment: @Steve you've helped out greatly no less!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes what would you suggest then that I do with the current set up?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that's correct of course. You can't write anything there, just read it back from the database. So just remove the code that tries to insert that number.

Comment: I need the category that it is pulling from though. The finances are all in categorys which is why we have that added into Access.  How would I do that if I removed it?

Comment: I have lost you now. You said that you have an autonumber in your Expenses table and now you need to get the Category. Could you add to your answer the exact schema of your two tables (Expenses and ExpenseType) and what is the relationship between these two tables?

Comment: @Steve I added a snapshot of our relationships and some description of what is going on to see if that helps you out? I edited the post.

Comment: Looking at the relationship I am pretty sure that the last part of my answer is the correct one for you. You load the combobox wirh both the ID and the Text but display only the text. When you enter a new expense you get the numeric value from the combo using the SelectedValue property (it is the ExpenseTypeID loaded from the ExpenseType table) and use that value to prepare the record to insert in the Expenses table.

Comment: @Steve so how would I go about researching to fix that? This is my FIRST database application, and my first of really anything VB outside of just displaying some bs text and a loop to a screen lol.  I actually commented that out to try to move along and then started getting errors about the connection not being open and then an error(after I fixed that one) saying command text not specified or something along those lines, so I'm thinking that this is pretty much all wrong -_-.  But, for starters, how would I go about keeping the category for the expense for the user into the db?

Comment: Can you post a zipped file with your code and the database (obviously stripping away any confidential information) on some public sharing site (OneDrive, GDrive etc) and post the link here? If I have a little time I could take a look at the whole, no promises though.

Comment: @Steve I would greatly appreciate it!  Like I said, I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, but I'm looking for guidance, and examples so I know what I am doing, if that makes sense? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tuhH3iERBHNDBNTEFPNEV5cFU/view?usp=sharing as you can see when you download, we have many iterations so far...this is the 13th.  The database is in the database folder.  Unless you're wanting to specify your own path as many of us have done, the one I sent you, goes to root C. Same with the help doc. That's basically it that I can think of.  Thank you again!

Comment: Looked at your code: In btnSubmitExpense_Click you have a SELECT instead of an INSERT INTO statement. In the same method you have commented out the parameter for the ExpenseTypeID. The remainder of your code should work if you follow the code to fill the combo and prepare the parameter for the ExpenseTypeID. By the way check all the references to your database file. They are not pointing at the same db everywhere. It is easy to be mislead in this conditions. Put the connection string in the app.config file and read it back from there EVERYWHERE.